# CodeIgniter Extending Multiple Controllers?

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance, out-of-memory, multiple-inheritance

Can't find a way to do this, possibly because there is another way to do this?

Some of my controllers extend AdminLayout and some of them extend ModLayout but I also need these pages to extend a LoggedIn Controller.

```
class Profile extends AdminLayout, LoggedIn {
```

However looking into there is no way to do this nicely. Is there a workaround?

Comment: At least your `LoggedIn` functionality should be put at the service layer, not at the controller layer.

Answer (score 25):

Assuming that you are using Codeigniter 2, this can be done by putting all you extended controller classes in the same file.

In */application/core* create a file called **MY_Controller.php** (don't forget to check the subclass prefix in *config.php* around line 109)

In here you can add all you controller classes to extend. For example;

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * MY_Controller Class
 *
 *
 * @package Project Name
 * @subpackage  Controllers
 */
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="form-error">', '</div>');
    }
}

class LoggedIn extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if (is_logged_in() == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('return_to', uri_string());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'You need to log in.');
            redirect('/home');
        }
    }
}

class AdminLayout extends LoggedIn {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // do something
    }
}

class ModLayout extends LoggedIn {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // do something
    }
}

/* End of file  */
/* Location: ./application/core/ */
```

Then when you create your controllers as per normal, just choose the base controller class to extend. Example;

```
class Foo extends AdminLayout {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if (is_logged_in() == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('return_to', uri_string());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'You need to log in.');
            redirect('/home');
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
class Bar extends ModLayout {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if (is_logged_in() == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('return_to', uri_string());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'You need to log in.');
            redirect('/home');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not support multiple inheritance.
You could use Codeigniter helpers or libraries for this.

Have a look at the library examples:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Simplelogin