# CodeIgniter-Multiple Sub Class Prefix

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to define multiple sub class prefix. Now the prefix is written in following format.

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = "MY";
```

Here I can create custom controller **MY_Controller**, which is appended with prefix "MY".

Here I want to create another custom controller called **MY_AdminController** along with MY_Controller. How do I define my subclass prefix in this situation.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494492/codeigniter-extending-multiple-controllers it seems to answer your question/problem

Comment: Sorry...Not exactly what I am looking for

Comment: You want to extend **MY_AdminController** from **MY_Controller** ? Or trying to extend the base controller multiple times ?

Comment: No I wanted to have two custom controller called **MY_AdminController** and **MY_Controller** and should be able to derive from any one of these two

Answer (score 1):

It´s too late but the right answer for me was to extend the CI_controller or MY_controller class, as you want, into the same file.. (sorry about my english)

`application/core/MY_controller.php`

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
   ...
   ...
   ...
}

class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller{
   ...
   do what you need
   ...
}

?>
```

I saw this answer in another post (can´t remember) and I solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

I have some tricks. I set a new configuration '`loading-cores`' on `config.php`. You can set the config name whatever you want.

```
$config['loading-cores'] = array(
    "load-my-cores" => TRUE,
    /* core class(es) to be loaded, note: must be a php file type */
    "my-cores" => ["APIResponder", "Anotherclass"]
);
```

> my classes in core folder:
>
> - APIResponder.php
> - Anotherclass.php

Then open file `..system/core/CodeIgniter.php`, try to find this snippet code:

```
if (file_exists(APPPATH.'core/'.$CFG->config['subclass_prefix'].'Controller.php')){
        require_once APPPATH.'core/'.$CFG->config['subclass_prefix'].'Controller.php';}
```

Add lines of codes below to load your core classes, place it right after the snippet code above:

```
if(isset($CFG->config['loading-cores'])){
    if($CFG->config['loading-cores']['load-my-cores'] && count($CFG->config['loading-cores']['my-cores']) > 0){
        foreach ($$CFG->config['loading-cores']['my-cores'] as $core) {
            if (file_exists(APPPATH."core/{$core}.php")){
                require_once APPPATH."core/{$core}.php";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Set `"load-my-cores" => FALSE` if you don't need the core classes to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one prefix.

What you're trying to do sounds like extending, You wish to extend an existing controller to do other stuff.

Don't forget that a controller is not just an abstract element, it's part of the MVC framework you're using.

the 'base' controller should not be specific(for example, adminController), it should be as general as possible and do 'controller' stuff(load views, load all your models etc.)

Let's say you have a users controller, an admin is a type of user, so it should extend the users model. This prevents you from doubling your code as admins should do at least some of the stuff users are doing. Just an example.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** not without tweaking the core

**Long answer:** you can hack your way around by adding a hook in `/system/core/CodeIgniter.php`, which will load your new controller before any others are loaded. Here's how I've done it:

(note that I use MY_Controller for the admin controllers and MY_Basecontroller for the regular ones):

1. Step one - you add this line to `/system/core/CodeIgniter.php, line 241` - [see exactly where](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/CodeIgniter.php#L241):

   ```
   $EXT->_call_hook('pre_local_controller');
   ```

   You must do this **just before** loading the local controller, otherwise it will not work.
2. Step two - add the following code to `/application/config/hooks.php`:

   ```
   $hook['pre_local_controller'][] = array(
                            'class'    => 'Hooks',
                            'function' => 'loadCore',
                            'filename' => 'Hooks.php',
                            'filepath' => 'hooks',
                            'params'   => 'MY_Basecontroller.php'
   );
   ```
3. Step three - create a file `/application/hooks/Hooks.php` and put the following code inside:

   ```
   class Hooks
   {
       public function loadCore($class)
       {
           require_once(APPPATH . 'core/' . $class);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Step four - profit

Now your classes can extend from the class `MY_Basecontroller` which resides in `/application/core/MY_Basecontroller.php`. Obviously, don't forget it should extend `CI_Controller`

It's still not exactly 'multiple subclass prefix' - actually it doesn't have anything to do with it, but will do what you asked for.

Tweak to your liking and go wild.

Cheers.

Comment: I did the same what you have mentioned above, but unfortunately I am getting this error,
**Fatal error: Class 'MY_Basecontroller' not found**

Comment: Which CodeIgniter version are you using? Also, in what file and line are you getting this error?

Comment: Version 2.1.4
I am getting error at class declaration area in Application controller,
**class User extends MY_Basecontroller {}**

Comment: Check `/application/config/config.php` for `$config['enable_hooks']`. Change it to true if it is not. 
If it is, put a `die();` statement in the `loadCore()` method from the Hooks class to see if it gets called.

Comment: `$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE`, and not getting called `loadCore()` method.

Comment: So the hooks are not loaded. Weird...
Try to change `$hook['pre_local_controller'][]` to `$hook['pre_controller'][]` while keeping the `die()` statement. If it dies, then the first step was not done properly. If it doesn't die, try to rename `/application/hooks/hooks.php` to `Hooks.php` (make the first letter uppercase) and see if that makes difference.

Comment: changed to `$hook['pre_controller'][]` , but no effect. Changed to Hooks.php but no change, still getting same error,`
Fatal error: Class 'MY_Basecontroller' not found in /var/www/codeigniter/application/controllers/admin/user.php on line 2`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't think of anything else that could be causing this, since the test case works fine with me. You'll have to do some debugging on your own to find out why the hooks are not being called. Check out the Hooks page of the CodeIgniter documentation for a sample hook to see how it should be working. If you manage to get hooks working, but still get that error, double-check all file names, path names and class names (case matters), make sure that controller is in `/application/core/MY_Basecontroller.php`, and that in its constructor you call `parent::__construct()`. Good luck!